# Как сделать функцию свайпа в PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5, qt5, swipe

Можно ли как то в `PyQt5` сделать функцию свайпа и при её выполнении выполнять действие? Мой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Button(QPushButton):
    mouseMoved = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseMoved.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("img.png")
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl.resize(216, 325)
        self.lbl.move(470, 1000)
        self.lbl.close()
        self.btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setMouseTracking(True);
        self.btn.setText("Кнопка")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("background: pink; color: Black; border-radius: 34px;}")
        self.btn.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn.move(430, 1550)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.image)
        self.show()
    def image(self):
        self.lbl.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, покажите что у вас уже есть и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Я только решил создать какую нибудь игру, продумал как будет все работать и необходима функция свайпа (в моем случае поворот вида в другую сторону как например в майнкрафте), кода пока нет